# Use of container docker as a proxy for CF app to get public IP

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I need a public IP for my application: is it a proper solution to use docker container as a proxy? I can see the price increasing quite a lot with all traffic going through proxy to reach the application. Is there any other option recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not do this.  The DEA's (part of Cloud Foundry that runs your app) is firewalled off from talking to internal IP's of other DEA's.  In Bluemix we do not charge for network bandwidth.

Comment: ok, then I should run my application in a Docker container and bind cloud foundry services in the catalogue using VCAP_SERVICES. Any other alternative?

Comment: Running your app in a docker container using the services is a good option.   What is your use case for a public ip?  Some direct non-HTTP acccess?

Comment: Yes, it is a requirement for security reason. There is a 3rd party service Statica in Bluemix catalogue which provides static IP addresses. This is an alternative to running the app in docker container.